# How to check undefined variable in a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an issue with ternary operation:

```
let a = undefined ? "Defined!" : "Definitely Undefined",
    b = abc ? "Defined!" : "Definitely Undefined", // ReferenceError
    c = (abc !== undefined) ? "Defined!" : "Definitely Undefined", // ReferenceError
    d = (typeof abc !== "undefined") ? "Defined!" : "Definitely Undefined"

// results: a = d = "Definitely Undefined", 
// while b and c throw ReferenceError when abc is undefined
```

What is the ***best and short way*** to check if abc is `undefined` before accessing its properties as well as assign blank object `{}` if `undefined`?

```
let a = [[best way to check abc]] ? {[abc.label1]: 2, [abc.label2]: 1} : {}
```

**PS:** I am currently using `(typeof abc !== "undefined")` in place of `[[best way to check abc]]`

Comment: why do you have an undeclared variable? or do you need just to check for `undefined`?

Comment: exactly, in my case I am expecting somebody to make that variable available for me :D

Comment: To be precise I am developing a generic code and lets say abc may or may not have been defined

Comment: @KiranShakya In that case, your code `typeof abc !== "undefined"` also fail right ? since `abc` is not defined ?

Comment: no! to clearify a bit, I use that part as condition for trinary operation as you can see in 4th line

Comment: in strict environment, undeclared variables throws an error by using that variable.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I am creating a generic utility service function which assumes, that variable be already declared. since it is a generic utility  it is loaded by by autoloader, and in most of the cases, that variable is already defined, except some rare cases, which I may not see right now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> while b and c throw ReferenceError when abc is undefined

So `abc` isn't just undefined, it's **undeclared**. There's a big difference there.

If you need to handle `abc` being undeclared, the only safe way to do that (without `try`/`catch`) is with `typeof`:

```
typeof abc === "undefined"
```

That will be true, without error, if `abc` is an undeclared identifier. It will also be true if `abc` is declared and contains the value `undefined`.

> What is the best and short way to check if `abc` is undefined before accessing its properties as well as assign blank object `{}` if undefined?

Probably using `var` to ensure it's declared:

```
var abc = abc || {};
```

Duplicate `var` declarations are not errors (duplicate `let` declarations are). So with the above, if `abc` is undeclared, it gets declared with the initial value `undefined` and we assign it `{}`. If it's declared, we replace its value with `{}` if it's falsy. **But**, if it may or may not be declared with `let` or `const`, then the above will throw an error as well.

So to handle the case where it may or may not be declared with `let` or `const`, we need a different variable entirely:

```
let ourabc = typeof abc === "undefined" || !abc ? {} : abc;
```

That sets `ourabc` to `{}` if `abc` is undeclared or if it contains a falsy value. Since all non-`null` object references are truthy, and you've said you want to access object properties, that's probably the shortest way.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning my spelling mistake, so using typeof is only the best bet here?

Comment: @KiranShakya: (No worries, and "trinary" *is* a word, just not *this* word. :-) ) `typeof` is the only safe way to check if an identifier is undeclared without throwing an error. The ReferenceError is catchable, though, so technically you could use `try`/`catch` as well, but it's more verbose and less efficient if this (`abc` being undeclared) isn't an exceptional situation.

Comment: `var abc = abc || {};` looks like it need a comment why this is right, if seen in code.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yeah. I mean, it's a common idiom, and yet as you say, it looks...wrong. :-) I've generally commented it in projects where we used it for pseudo-namespaces (e.g., ones that don't use proper modules).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, so if I always expect object to be its type, then I can do `let a = typeof abc === "object" ? abc : {}`. Technically it is shorter and correct :)

Comment: @KiranShakya: Nice one, but you'd need a `null` check on that (because `typeof null` is `"object"`). So perhaps `let a = typeof abc === "object" && abc ? abc : {};` since the only falsy thing that's `typeof "object"` is `null`.

Answer (score 9):

```
   state = (typeof state !== "undefined") ? state : '';
```

This way you can check undefined variable in a ternary operator.

Comment: thanks, simple and what I was looking

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best and short way to check if abc is undefined before accessing its properties as well as assign blank object {} if undefined?

And you said that

*I am currently using (typeof abc !== "undefined")*

Looks like you have abc defined and the value is `undefined`.

You can try doing

```
var a = abc || {};
console.log(a);
```

Comment: What if `abc` is `0`?